In cypress, I wanted to execute a flow based on a web locator visiblity. How to achieve it?
In my web page I have a locator which is identified by...
cy.get('.app-text')
In my case, I want to execute different flows based on the visibility of the above locator in the page.
If above locator is visible i want to execute one flow, if not another work flow.
How to achieve it using cypress and typescrip

Cypress considers this kind of conditional testing an anti pattern.
Meaning, it's probably a bad idea to write conditional tests in the first place.
(See here: https://docs.cypress.io/app/guides/conditional-testing#)
Anyways, your use case could be achieved like this:
describe("conditinal testing", () => {
  it("logs 'IF'", () => {
    cy.visit("https://www.google.com/");
    conditinalTestingAntiPattern();
  });

  it("logs 'ELSE'", () => {
    conditinalTestingAntiPattern();
  });
});

function conditinalTestingAntiPattern() {
  cy.then(() => {
    const searchInput = cy.$$('[name="q"]');
    if (searchInput) {
      cy.log("IF");
    } else {
      cy.log("ELSE");
    }
  });
}


